# How to create a page without custom master page

Tags: master-page, web-part-page

How to create a page without custom master page. I want v4 master page for that page.

Comment: A webpart is not a page, so it does not use a master page

Comment: i want to create a page that does not inherit master page but it has its own master page v4.

Comment: Then your question should probably state that and not webpart

Comment: how can we do it .

Comment: Mayby a application page? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231581.aspx

Answer (score 1):

How about a application page? [Creating Application Pages for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231581.aspx)

> "An application page is an ASP.NET Web page that is designed for use
>   in a SharePoint Web site. Application pages are a specialized type of
>   ASP.NET page. The primary difference between an application page and a
>   standard ASP.NET page is that an application page contains content
>   that is merged with a SharePoint master page. A master page enables
>   application pages to share the same appearance and behavior as other
>   pages on a site.
>
> You can explicitly change which master page is used by the application
>   page by setting the MasterPageFile attribute of the application Page
>   element. (For example:
>   MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/applicationv4.master"). In fact, you must
>   set this attribute if dynamic master pages are not enabled on the
>   SharePoint server."

Comment: what i have done is simply created one page and chage its master page throw designer . thnx.

Comment: Jon, so your problem is resoloved?

Comment: @Christoffer but we can't use asp.net standard pages in SharePoint though can we ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the MasterPage on a non-publishing site via 'Change the Look' in site settings.

Simply navigate to Site settings then click on “Change the look”.
[image: Site Settings - Change the look]

On the Themes page click on the theme that you are using.
[image: Themes page]

Next on the left pane you can select the master page for this theme.
[image: Select masterpage]

Next click on “Try it Out” and then “Yes, keep it”

and you’re done

[These instructions were provided by LearningSharePoint.com](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/07/21/sharepoint-2013-how-to-change-the-master-page-of-your-sharepoint-site/)

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question of how to create a page without a masterpage?

Comment: His comment on May 20th suggested that he wanted to change the MasterPage.  Sorry if I was incorrect or if this post was unhelpful.